# problems when installing git

Tags: git, makefile, installation, doc

I cloned the current [source tree](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/INSTALL) and tried to build it and I get the following error. 
Could someone tell me why and if there is an easy way to fix it? 
I’m running on a Ubuntu system.

```
    Build steps:
     $ make configure ;# as yourself
     $ ./configure --prefix=/usr ;# as yourself
     $ make all doc ;# as yourself
(errors occur)
    .
    .
    .
    ASCIIDOC technical/shallow.html
    ASCIIDOC technical/trivial-merge.html
    GEN technical/api-index.txt    
    ASCIIDOC technical/api-index.html
    sed "s|@@MAN_BASE_URL@@|file:///usr/local/share/doc/git/|" manpage-base-url.xsl.in > manpage-base-url.xsl
    ASCIIDOC git-add.xml
    XMLTO git-add.1
    compilation error: file /tmp/xmlto-xsl.ORAr7p line 6 element include
    xsl:include : invalid URI reference /home/gary/下载/git/Documentation/manpage-normal.xsl
    compilation error: file /tmp/xmlto-xsl.ORAr7p line 7 element include
    xsl:include : invalid URI reference /home/gary/下载/git/Documentation/manpage-base-url.xsl
    make[1]: *** [git-add.1] 错误 1
    make[1]:正在离开目录 `/home/gary/下载/git/Documentation'
    make: *** [doc] 错误 2
```

Comment: Have you tried to put everything in a dir that doesn't contain characters like 下载 ?

Comment: The characters "下载" lead to these errors! I have fixed it.

Comment: I had the same problem when the path to the git project contained characters outside the ASCII space — in my case, my username. Changing the location solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Zloj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239879/zloj) has answered my question in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863563/problems-when-installing-git/33580473#comment53560190_32863563):

> Have you tried to put everything in a dir that doesn't contain characters like 下载 ?